# Delete OSX partition and join remainder to Windows 7 partition

Tags: windows-7, macos, partitioning, ssd

I have an iMac 27" with a SSD that has OSX installed on it. I used Boot Camp to install Windows 7 partition. I found myself using Windows 7 more then OSX because I have a PC at work so I would like to gain the additional SSD space for Windows 7. So here's my question:

How do I remove the OSX and recover the remaining SSD space so I can make it part of the Windows 7 without having to reinstall Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Before you do this, realize that if you have to reinstall Windows, you will have to go through this process again.  You will have to reinstall OS X, use the Bootcamp process to get the latest drivers from Apple for Windows, then install Windows and go through the process of removing OS X.  Also, if there is an EFI update you can **ONLY** apply it if you are using OS X.  Easiest solution is to just minimize the partition size of OS X, and maximize the Win7 partition.  It gives the added benefit of having a recovery partition.

Comment: Thanks for such a fast response! Will keep you posted on how it turns out.

Comment: How do I minimize the partition sizes as you recommend is the easiest approach? Thanks!

Comment: @RickSands using a LiveCD such as GParted should take care of this.

Comment: Thanks, D/L GParted and tested it here at work; perfect. Now I'm ready to try it this weekend on my iMac. Thanks everyone will report back with update.....wish me luck!  :)

Comment: Well...... GParted worked liked advertised but when I went to reboot, it didn't recognize the boot rive. I read to put the Windows 7 CD in and boot from there. Then repair the boot drive using the Windows 7 CD. But that had no success. So after 20 minutes I was able to format the SSD boot drive and install Windows 7. Not to bad...but a learning curve for sure. After completing the install with all the updates I can not see the 1 Tera HDD drive that I saved everything on. Any ideas on what I should try next?  Thanks for taking the time to help me on this adventure.    Rick

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a LiveCD, such as http://gparted.sourceforge.net/, remove the partitions pertaining to your Mac OS, then extend your Windows partition to take over the rest of the drive.

Not sure what complications that could arise from this as I don't deal with Macs, but that's the general solution.

Comment: Thanks for such a fast response!  Will research this option and see which one I end up trying first. Thanks!